# What caused the difference between these two code blocks?

Tags: sql-server, database

I use two blocks to seek the same outcome, i.e assign an associated value to a new created column.

Block 1: worked

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable 
SET [BorrowerAccountId]=a.Account_Id
FROM dbo.MyTable m
JOIN dbo.Account   a
ON m.AppReference=a.App_Reference
```

Block 2: not worked.
         It return: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable  
SET [BorrowerAccountId]=(SELECT DISTINCT Account_Id 
FROM  dbo.Account a
         WHERE a.App_Reference=AppReference)
```

Actually, I had checked the table dbo.Account and get to know one App_Reference can only have one Account_Id. So the problem seemed irrelevant to the data structure in table dbo.Account. 
I think it should be the issue of the clause's working machanism. I may miss something. 
Cheers

Comment: Well, the problem is exactly explained in the error message: "Subquery returned more than 1 value". Group by `dbo.Account.App_Reference` and select all the rows with `COUNT(*) > 1` to find the abusive rows.

Comment: select AppReference, Count(account_id) from dbo.Account group by AppReference having count(account_id) > 1, run this query, and see whether you get any records, if yes, that's why your Block 2 does not work.

Comment: @zerkms All was 1. And if it had COUNT(*) > 1, the block 1 should face the same error as well. Cheers

Comment: @LUSAQX "All was 1" --- sql server tells the opposite. Show the exact query. " the block 1 should face the same error as well" --- nope.

Comment: in your subquery replace DISTINCT with TOP 1, if it works, then sure you have duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

In Block 2, I think it returned a table data with all Account_Id's such that the associated App_Reference can be found at least once in table MyTable. So it contained multiple value legitimately.